# parec not working via ssh

Tags: sound, ssh, pulseaudio

I am trying to use scripts such as [sox and rec without the mic | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834961/sox-and-rec-without-the-mic) and [recording from PulseAudio | outflux.net](http://www.outflux.net/blog/archives/2009/04/19/recording-from-pulseaudio/)

If I ssh into the box and try to run any command such as

```
pactl list short sources
```

I get back

```
root@blue:~# pactl list short sources
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
root@blue:~#
```

I get the same if I try parec. Now if I try it from the desktop it works fine. I am using Ubuntu 16.0.4. Any idea what would cause this? Doing the same on CentOS 7 has no such issue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, `xcb_connection_has_error` is part of:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ man xcb_connection_has_error
No manual entry for xcb_connection_has_error
walt@bat:~(16)$ man -k xcb_connection_has_error
xcb_connection_has_error: nothing appropriate.
walt@bat:~(16)$ man -k xcb_connection
xcb_connection: nothing appropriate.
walt@bat:~(16)$ man -k xcb
DES_xcbc_encrypt (3ssl) - DES encryption
XGetXCBConnection (3) - get the XCB connection for an Xlib Display
XSetEventQueueOwner (3) - set event queue owner on a shared Xlib/XCB connection
```

X Windows. What's your `$DISPLAY` variable set to on both systems? Have you tried the `-v`, `-X` and `-x` options to your `ssh` command?

Since `strings  $(type -p pactl) | grep DISPLAY` returns 1 (no match), `pactl` does NOT directly make use of X Windows and cannot get X Windows errors(`xcb_connection_has_error`).

Comment: when I ssh into the CentOS box and do echo $DISPLAY I get nothing. On the Ubuntu box if I ssh in remotely it's blank as well. On the Ubuntu box if I do ssh@localhost again $DISPLAY is blank. On the Ubuntu box if I do ssh -X root@localhost then $DISPLAY is localhost:10.0 AND I am able to run parec. Here is what is very interesting. If I ssh in remotely to the ubuntu box parec wont work. However if I now do export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0 the next time I try parec it will work. It will only work so long as there is a local ssh session. If that goes away it stops working.